# Laravel Telescope is not working in production with Laravel Voyager. How to secure /telescope/* routes in Laravel 7?

Tags: production, laravel-7, voyager

I'm using Laravel with Auth, Auth UI, Voyager admin panel, Telescope. Everything works fine untill I change `APP_ENV=local` to `APP_ENV=production` in .env file. When I change the .env file to production then I get the below error. screen shot of my issue is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0P8m.png).

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Basically I want to protect `/telescope/*`routes in production. But before doing that I am getting this error.
I read the same issue in github [similar issue github link](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3991). I think the answer is present in the link but im unable to digest it as im a newbie.
Any help to fix this, and protecting telescope routes in production is much appreciated. I tried to create a Policy and give read permissions to the user via policy. But somehow im not able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

ok: its too easy - the only thing you have to do is:

```
php artisan make:policy -m User UserPolicy
```

thats it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the array of email into the gate method in the `TelescopeServiceProvider.php`

```
       Gate::define('viewTelescope', function ($user) {
            return in_array($user->email, [
                'username@domain.com'
            ]);
        });
```

This will block everyone except the mentioned email of logged-in user.